# What's the order of scalability (cost and throughput) between these directly connected network topologies?

Tags: networking, architecture, system, scalability

I need to know the order of scalability (cost and speed of transfer) between these network topologies: Fully connected, linear, ring, 2D net, 2D torus (they are the 2D extensions of the previous ones), and hypercube.

I would like to order them, by the value of their scalability. For example, the fully connected has one of the best values by the speed of transfer, as each element is connected to all other elements, but has the lowest value by cost, because you have to connect each new element to all the others.

Sorry, if the terminology, or the question itself is somewhat incorrect, I'm not really an expert in this field, but I need some sort of an answer for this question.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the "order of scalability"?

Comment: I would like to order them, by the value of their scalability. For example, the fully connected has one of the best values by the speed of transfer, as each element is connected to all other elements, but has the lowest value by cost, because you have to connect each new element to all the others. (It is a usual test question in universities.) I have extended the original question, to help complete understanding, thanks for that.

Comment: There is no plain scalability, there is bandwidth (point-to-point and bisection) and there is cost. What is the exact test question?

Comment: Usually, they give you three, or four of these topologies, and you have to put them in increasing order (from worst to best), by a given property, which is either the cost of the network (as you mentioned), or (which is the more problematic) neither point-to-point, or bisection (I have the equations for those) but overall bandwidth.

(In my language, we use the word 'scalability' for the fact, that the larger these networks are, they are becoming more costly, so the scalability by cost is better or worse for one topology or another.)

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a hard egg to crack:), here is an exact example: Rank these topologies: fully connected, linear, ring, hypercube in increasing order by their cost.

Comment: Do you ask about cost or about cost and bandwidth or about bandwidth? What kind of cost model do you use? (Should we estimate bigger costs of designing high radix ASIC switches? Can we assume modern HW or should we estimate for 1990s, 2000s, 2030s?). Did you try any textbooks: page 55 of https://www.cs.uky.edu/~jzhang/CS621/chapter3.pdf or any book on networks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can list some parameters of listed networks, for example by using page 55 "3.16c: Characteristics of Static Networks" of https://www.cs.uky.edu/~jzhang/CS621/chapter3.pdf

> Parallel and Distributed Computing. Chapter 3: Models of Parallel Computers and
>   Interconnections

by Jun Zhang, Laboratory for High Performance Computing & Computer Simulation, Department of Computer Science, University of Kentucky

The parameters for network of `p` machines (nodes) are:

- Links per node - every node will have one or more links; some networks will have multiport switches too (star, tree=star_of_stars)
- Link per network - total number of links (cables) in network
- Diameter - how many transit nodes (switches) will be passed (worst number)
- Bisection width - how many links should be removed to separate network into two unconnected halves

> Fully connected,

There is direct connection between every pair of nodes, `p` links per node, `p*(p-1)/2` links in network (very high), diameter of 1 (best possible), bisection width `p*p/4`

> linear bus, (linear array)

There are typically one (shared medium; can't be scaled up) or two connections (point to point) per node. With p2p connections first and last node has only 1 link. Links per network = `p-1`, diameter = `p-1`, bisection width = 1.

> ring,

Two connections per node (left/right; it is 1D torus), p connections (links) in network. Diameter `p-2` (mean p/2), bisection width 2.

> 2D net (2d mesh)

Every node has 4 connections (up/down/right/left), but nodes at edge have some unconnected. The network of p nodes is square figure with height = `sqrt(p)`. `2*(p-sqrt(p))` connected links in network, diameter `2*(sqrt(p)-1)`, bisection width of `sqrt(p)`.

> 2D torus

Every node has 4 connections (up/down/right/left), nodes at edge have connection to other edge. `2*p` connected links in network, diameter `~sqrt(p)`, bisection width of `2*sqrt(p)`.

> hypercube

Hypercube on `n` dimensions has `p=2^n` nodes, so `n = log_2 (p)`. So, every node has link per dimension - `n` links or `log(p)`. There are `p*log(p)/2` connected links in network, `log(p)` diameter, `p/2` bisection width.

Try to calculate some numbers for p=10; p=100; p=10000. There can be different network cost models, for example we can model some cost of each port and of each cable by using "links per network" parameter, for example, we can have $100 per port and $10 cable (or $500 port; no more 2 ports per card and 70$ short cable / 500$ long cable). Or we can use some cost of every network card.. Or we can afford some switches, but  we will have no full bisection bandwidth....

Comment: Thank you, I think with the attached advice, this answer should do the trick, and I marked it as correct.